# Is a cider-like smell a bad sign in a culture of beer yeast?

Tags: beer, yeast, first-time, yeast-cultures

I started culturing yeast from a La Fin Du Monde bottle about 3 days ago.  I have since stepped it up to a 2L container about half full of wort.  I have been very careful about sanitizing everything and the yeast are growing like crazy.  Right now there is a fair amount of sediment at the bottom and always a bunch of krausen along the top of the wort.

My question is about the smell.  I have read that a foul smell is bad, and it doesn't smell foul, but it does smell like a glass of La Fin Du Monde that has been mixed with some cider... definitely a far more cidery smell than that of a bottle conditioned beer.

Is this an "off" smell for culturing yeast, or is this on par?  I have never done this before, so I just want to make sure that a slight to medium cidery smell was not an indication of a contaminated culture.

The wort mixture I am using is 1/2 cup Extra-light DME, to 1 quart of water, boiled for about 5 minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should probably state your question closer to "Is a cider like smell a bad sign in a yeast culture?", your title doesn't indicate what you're asking.  Please do update with results, as I'm curious.

Comment: I pitched a 2L starter into my primary last night on my first batch ever!  The krausen was so big it popped my top off, so I quickly re-sterilized put it back on, and developed a blow off valve system similar to what I have seen on some carboys.  Let's hope it turns out okay, I will fill you in on if the beer comes close to La Fin Du Monde's flavor.

Comment: Is it bottled yet?  If so, how did it turn out?

Comment: I bottled last week (April 12th).  I will let you guys know how it turns out in a couple more weeks!

Comment: Yo Carson let us know how it went!!

Comment: The beer turned out great!  It has a distinct Unibroue flavor along with the other flavors I added.  If you like La Fin Du Monde then I would recommend culturing your own yeast from a bottle or two!

Comment: Carson, You should come back and answer your own question (you're allowed to do that).  Nice that you put a note here, that it turned out great, but the question still shows as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry I have been MIA.

The beer turned out great - it had an extremely similar flavor profile to La Fin Du Monde, and since I used corriander and sweet orange peel, tasted similar to a La Fin Du Monde mixed with an Allagash white in my opinion.

So, the smell given off when I was culturing must have just been a normal smell given off by the yeast.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be the one to burst your bubble, but as far as I know, Unibruoe filters out their primary yeast strain and uses a separate one for bottle conditioning. So even if you did have some non-contaminated yeast, it's most likely not the stuff you are looking for.

Comment: I know that this link is fairly old, but I based my culture on this: http://www.nada.kth.se/~alun/Beer/Bottle-Yeasts/